# How to interface two Raspberry Pi CM4 modules and a SOM CN9130 module

Tags: ethernet, pcie, module, cm4

I am working on project that requires two [Raspberry Pi CM4 modules](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/compute-module-4/?variant=raspberry-pi-cm4001000) and a [SOM CN9130 module](https://www.cnx-software.com/2021/06/10/clearfog-cn9130-networking-boards-deliver-10gbe-through-a-tiny-octeon-tx2-module/) to communicate each other with a data speed of 1GBPS.

Both modules have Ethernet and support the PCIe bus.

What would be the most effective way to interface these modules?

I have two ideas: one through Ethernet and another is through PCIe bus.

Through Ethernet:

[image]

Through PCIe bus:

[image]

Comment: According to this thread, https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=320074 , the rpi doesn’t suppprt endpoint mode, so that might prevent pcie altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only two modules, you can shorten Ethernet to a single set of magnetics between the two PHYs, giving you a direct link.

For PCIe, you'd need some kind of non-transparent bridge (NTB), as both CM4 modules only support root mode, not endpoint mode. Linux brings some [NTB support](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/ntb.txt), but AFAIK the drivers that are included support only CPU embedded NTBs for Intel and AMD CPUs.

A quick search for "pcie discrete ntb" found the [Renesas PES32NT24G2](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/apn/717-using-89h32nt24g2-pci-express-switch-multi-root-compute-storage-and-communications-systems?language=en), so readymade ICs do exist -- you'd need to check other vendors and models, verify driver support etc. to get a proper solution and not just a quick feasibility check.